# Closed continuous operator has closed domain? Question about completeness

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, closed-graph

This question is about the statement:

Let $X$, $Y$ be normed linear spaces and $D$ a linear subspace of $X$ and suppose that $A\colon D \to Y$ is a linear operator.  If $A$ is continuous and closed and $Y$ complete, then $D$ is closed.

I was playing around a bit and tried to employ some techniques I had recently picked up in topology class in order to avoid tedious arguments with sequences (attempt at proof below):

Define $T: D\times D \to D \times Y$ by $T(x,x)=(x,Ax)$. Then $G_A=T(D\times D)$, where $G_A$ is the graph of $A$. Also, since $A, I$ are bounded, so is $T$ in the product norm and hence it is continuous. Thus $T^{-1}(G_A)=T^{-1}(T(D\times D))=D\times D$ is the inverse image of a closed under a continuous map and so is closed. Now $D=\Lambda^{-1}(D\times D)$ under the diagonal map $\Lambda$ which is continuous and hence $D$ is closed.

Now, I suspect that I messed up since I didn't use the completeness of $Y$ (and also I saw it proved in class in the standard way using completeness of $Y$). Could someone put me on the right track?

After some discussion it appears I was sloppy with defining the operator $T$ above. My counter-argument would then be to adjust as following (2nd attempt):

First define $U=\{(x,y) \in D\times D: x=y\}=G_I$. Since $U$is the graph of the identity it is a normed linear space as well. Now define $T:U \to D \times Y$ by $T(x,x)=(x,Ax)$. Then $G_A=T(U)$, where $G_A$ is the graph of $A$. Also, since $A, I$ are bounded, so is $T$ in the product norm and hence it is continuous. Thus $T^{-1}(G_A)=T^{-1}(T(U))=U$ is the inverse image of a closed under a continuous map and so is closed. Now $D=\Lambda^{-1}(U)$ under the diagonal map $\Lambda$ which is continuous and hence $D$ is closed.

Third attempt. I think I have found a construction which eliminates the issues highlighted by commenters and also uses the fact that $Y$ is a Banach space (thank you very much):

We begin with a lemma:

Let $X$ be a normed linear space and $Y$ a Banach space. If $A: D \subset X \to Y$ is a linear operator there exists a continuous extension of $A$ to all of $X$ such that $\hat A x= Ax$ for $x\in D$.

Define $S(x)=(x,Ax)$ and $\hat S(x)=(x,\hat Ax)$, where $\hat A$ is a continuous extension of $A$. Then $\hat S$ is a continuous extension of $S$. Note that $\hat Sx \in G_A \Rightarrow x\in D$. Now take $\hat S^{-1}(G_A)=D$. Hence $D$ is the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function from $X$, so it is closed.

Comment: What do you mean by $T(D)$ in the first line of your third paragraph? You defined $T$ to be a map from the product space $D\times D$ so how can it take in $D$ as input? Also what is $G_A$ ?

Comment: Sorry, $T(D)$ was supposed to be $T(D\times D)$ and $G_A$the graph of $A$.

Comment: I think I see the problem. You only defined $T$ on the diagonal. In general, shouldn't you have to tell me what $T(x,y)$ is?

Comment: Hm yes, that seems indeed to be a mistake on my part. What if I took $T: diag(D \times D) \to D\times Y$ instead  and just replace $D\times D$ everywhere with the diagonal? I'll make an edit so that it viewed more easily in context.

Comment: If we eliminate useless gymnastics, you're looking at the continuous map $S \colon D \to X\times Y$ given by $S(x) = (x,Ax)$. Now you use the closedness of $G_A$ and the continuity of $S$ to deduce that $D = S^{-1}(G_A)$ is closed. But since the domain of $S$ is $D$, you only get that $D$ is closed in $D$ - which is nothing new.

Comment: Ahuh, now I understand. I suspected there was a deeper mistake somewhere. Thank you very much for clarifying. Case closed.

Comment: Maybe one could use the continuous extension of your $S$? However, then one might run into problems with the inverse image which I don't see a way around.

Comment: Maybe you solved it already, but here is a short argument: Let $x_n\to x$ in $X$, where $x_n\in D$. Because $A$ is bounded, then $\|Ax_n-Ax_m\|_Y\leq \|A\|\|x_n-x_m\|_Y\to 0$ and therefore $Ax_n$ is Cauchy in $Y\Rightarrow Ax_n\to y\in Y$. But $A$ is closed and so $x\in D$ and $Ax=y\Rightarrow D$ is closed.

Comment: Thanks Svetoslav. I'll give it a +1. Althought, the point of the question was not really to provide "a proof" (which was discussed in class actually) but rather to investigate the, specific, alternate route above.